# Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps & RefAttributes<Map>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, leaflet

Onclick doesn't work on the mapcontainer, can anyone help with that?

```
Function handleMapClick:

function handleMapClick(event: LeafletMouseEvent ) {

    }
```

MapContainer with onClick:

```
<MapContainer center={[ -5.2137252, -37.3292853]} zoom={12} onClick={handleMapClick}>
```

Error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: Element[]; center: [number, number]; zoom: number; onClick: (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps & RefAttributes<Map>'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MapContainerProps & RefAttributes<Map>'.
```

````
import React, { useEffect, useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react';```
````

Comment: Where are you importing `MapContainer` from?